# gnuplot plot scientific notation (exponential value on x-axis)

Tags: plot, format, gnuplot, scientific-notation, blast

I'm new using gnuplot, today I learned a lot on stackoverflow for a problem that I had with a plot, but now for my research I need to do another one like the following image:

[image]

The data are of the same tipe, I collected them and isolate only the column that I need in a file.dat, and a sample is the following:

```
5.38e-51 1
2.75e-81 1
5.3e-67 1
8.71e-170 4
3.62e-59 3
2.98e-52 2
3.2e-31 1
2.98e-54 2
3.85e-29 2
5.38e-57 1
3.2e-33 2
2.75e-88 1
3.2e-34 1
9.89e-37 1
5.38e-59 2
3.2e-35 2
1.68e-168 1
1.81e-101 1
9.89e-39 1
2.98e-59 2
3.2e-39 1
1.07e-110 3
1.07e-111 2
1.81e-107 2
2.82e-40 4
2.6e-108 1
1.07e-115 1
```

My problem is that I would like on the x-axis that my x is the exponent, as 1E-x.
I tried using set format `set format x '%.0f'.sprintf('e%d')` but it doesn't work.
How can I do that?
thank you.

Comment: What do you actually want to plot? Just these numbers? From the graph you show, I would guess you want some histogram with logarithmic bins, correct?

Comment: yes exactly I would like the same graph, I updated the main topic data with the counts that i can have for each value

Comment: I want to recrate the same plot, having as x the exponent of 1e-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to plot values which span many order of magnitudes you either plot it on logarithmic scale
or take `log10()` of your values and plot them in linear scale.
From your description without code and details, I'm guessing that you have
the data you've shown and want to create a histogram and display the negative `log10` value on the x-axis.

**NB:** In your earlier data you had also `0.0`, which will mess-up the `smooth freq` option together with the logarithmic bins. Note that `set datafile missing "0.0"` will only exclude `0.0` as text, i.e. `0`, `0.00`, or `0e-10` will not be excluded. So, make sure you don't have zeros in your data, this will not work with logarithmic scale.

**Code:**

```
### plot histogram with logarithmic bins
reset session

$Data <<EOD
5.38e-51   1
2.75e-81   1
5.3e-67    1
8.71e-170  4
3.62e-59   3
2.98e-52   2
3.2e-31    1
2.98e-54   2
3.85e-29   2
5.38e-57   1
3.2e-33    2
2.75e-88   1
3.2e-34    1
9.89e-37   1
5.38e-59   2
3.2e-35    2
1.68e-168  1
1.81e-101  1
9.89e-39   1
2.98e-59   2
3.2e-39    1
1.07e-110  3
1.07e-111  2
1.81e-107  2
2.82e-40   4
2.6e-108   1
1.07e-115  1
EOD

set xlabel "-log_{10}(x)"
set xrange[-15:200]
set xtics 10 out
set ylabel "Sequences"
set yrange [0:]
set key noautotitle

# Histogram with logarithmic bins
BinWidth = 10 
Bin(x)   = floor(-log10(x)/BinWidth)*BinWidth + BinWidth*0.5

set boxwidth BinWidth
set style fill solid 0.3
set offset 1,1,1,0
set grid x,y

set datafile missing "0.0"    # exclude zero, otherwise it will mess up "smooth freq"

plot $Data u (Bin($1)):2 smooth freq with boxes lc "red"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! this is very helpful, otherwise my idea was to keep the e scale like the plot I shared, so having on the x-axis the exponent of the e in my values multiply by 1. I'm not sure I explained myself good enough

Comment: @Chiara Not sure I understand. You can plot the data as is, but then you need to set `set logscale x` and maybe `set format x "%T"`. Check `help format_specifiers`. But then you still have to get rid of the minus.

Comment: Yes, but i would like to have the data not in - log scale but i don't want to lose the n*e^(exponent) format (like the plot I shared).

Comment: @Chiara how do you want to plot 1e-10 in the same graph with 1e-153 without logscale?

Comment: @Chiara are you talking about the xlabel formatting or the xtic formatting? Do you maybe want: `set xlabel '1E^{-x}'`?

Comment: I would like to plot only the exponent of the e, so having on x-axis both the 10 and the 153, like in the plot I shared that on the x I have 1*e^(-x) where I'm plotting this x

Comment: @Chiara Sorry, I don't get your point. You can get the exponent of your number by calculating `log10(...)`.

Comment: I'm sorry you are perfectly right, in my head I was looking for something else but I was wrong.  thanks again for the help, the plot is perfect!